# A .txt file to display a tree beginning with the current directory and all PDF files by DIR Command

Tags: directory

I am new for DIR Command.
I'm wondering if I can list the current directory at the first line followed by the filenames of all PDF files inside by DIR COMMAND.

For example, the target directory is C:\MyWork and there are 3 PDF files, named PDF1, PDF2, and PDF3 inside the folder.
Can I have a .txt file which lists:
MyWork
PDF1
PDF2
PDF3
*without file extension

Also, do the same thing for the subfolders under the 'MyWork' folder except for the 'Working' folder.
For example, there are two subfolders, 'Final' and 'Working', under the 'MyWork' folder, and 3 PDFs (PDF1_1, PDF2_1, and PDF3_1) inside the folder 'Final', then the list will be:
MyWork
PDF1
PDF2
PDF3
Final
PDF1_1
PDF2_1
PDF3_1
...
and so on.
*skip the folder named 'Working'

Thank you.

With my limited knowledge, I can list all PDF filenames (without file extension) only under the target path ..

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if exist Filelist.txt del Filelist.txt

for %%A in ("C:\MyWork\*.pdf") do (
    set "filename=%%~nA"
    set "filename=!filename:XXX_=!"
    echo !filename! >> Filelist.txt
)

endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list your folder, subfolders and files without extensions try combining for loops with 'Tree /f' command like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_dst_folder=C:\MyWork"

::check for .txt file existence & delete if found
if exist Filelist.txt (
    del Filelist.txt
)

:: Tree your folders & subfolders files
:: through iterating with tree command

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in (`tree "%_dst_folder%" /f`) do (
    set "_fnames=%%~nA"
    echo !_fnames! >> Filelist.txt
) 
endlocal
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But can we skip the folder named 'Working' and only list PDF filenames?

Answer (score 1):

> Thank you so much! But can we skip the folder named 'Working' and only list PDF filenames? –

Of course! There are many ways to do this, but if you just want to use `for` loops, here is a simple solution

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_dst_folder=C:\MyWork"

:: Change to destination folder with 'PUSHD' command
pushd "%_dst_folder%"

::check for .txt file existence & delete if found
if exist Filelist.txt (
    del Filelist.txt
)
:: Loop through *.pdf/ *.xlsx/ *.txt or whatever files and echo filenames
for %%A in (*.pdf) do (
    set "_fnames=%%~nA"
    echo !_fnames! >> Filelist.txt
)

endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

Your top level folder requirement (with extensions) is met by one line:

```
echo %cd%>filelist.txt&&dir /b *.pdf>>filelist.txt
```

The first > will overwrite any previous run.
The second >> will then append the filenames under the first line.

The need to exclude extensions makes that simple solution way harder. So the core command is then:

```
echo %cd%>filelist.txt&&forfiles /M *.pdf /c "cmd /V:ON  /c set f=@fname&echo !f:~1,-1!"
```

Thus for each folder and sub folder you could simply run the one line. So you need to consider how to run that simple line in each sub folder and where the output should go.

If the desire is one filelist per folder then run above single line in each folder except the one you don't need.

If the data needs to be appended to one level up then amend the subfolders task to:

```
echo/ >>../filelist.txt&&echo %CD%>>../filelist.txt&&dir /b *.pdf>>../filelist.txt
```

There are many other ways to approach your task, but the aim is for you to experiment based on corrections and suggestions, not write a full code for the task.

However, to guide you without expansion, after first one line example, try this at a console in the top working directory. Again this includes the .pdf extension so consider how forfiles in second one line example is handling string stripping.

```
echo/ >>filelist.txt&&for /f %f in ('dir /s /b /a:d') do echo/ >>%cd%/filelist.txt&&echo %f>>%cd%/filelist.txt&&dir /b %f\*.pdf>>%cd%/filelist.txt
```

Your stipulation that there must be an exclusion (not one sub directory branch) is not easy in such a simple command line, but you can spread the commands in a batch file by replacing && with a line feed. Then add an exclusion at the point required by `if %%f == blah then goto skip`, and there are examples of that elsewhere for your added complexity.